# Distribution of partial trace of Haar unitary

Tags: probability, haar-distribution

I am sure this must have been covered in the mathematical literature, but hoping someone can direct me to the right place.

Let us be given random unitaries $U$ on $n$ qubits (so dimension of the space is $2^n$) distributed according to the Haar measure.

Define the partial trace of such unitaries on $k \leq n$ qubits, $W = \text{Tr}_{1,\cdots,k} U$, so that $W$ acts on $n-k$ qubits.

1. Is there a nice closed form expression of the distribution of $W$ for any $n,k$? (Note in the limit when $n,k$ is large, I believe $W$ should be distributed according to the Ginibre ensemble [unless I'm mistaken], but here I'm asking for the induced distribution for arbitrary $n,k$)
2. Is there a computationally/numerically efficient way of generating the random matrices $W$ without generating the full $U$ and performing the partial trace?

Comment: Do you know what the answer is for $k=1$? $n=2$? Also by "the Haar measure" I presume you mean the circular unitary distribution for SU($2^n$)?

Comment: @QuantumMechanic I can calculate low moments of the random variable, but it would be nice to get the full distribution. And yes, unitaries drawn from the CUE for matrices of dim $2^n$. The standard name this uniform distribution is called the Haar measure though (this is standard terminology in quantum computing and math)

Comment: Can you say anything about the distribution of the trace or the determinant? The CUE tells us the distribution of eigenvalues of $U$, and the eigenvalues of $W$ must sum to the eigenvalues of $U$, so we can write the distribution of the trace of $W$. The determinants won't be the same, but maybe there's some constraint?